# Dropdown navbar gets covered by contents

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to create a landing page for a photoshop layout. I am quite new to HTML and CSS and I am having trouble solving this. My drop-down menu lists are getting covered by the content. I think it might be about positioning... Thanks
I will attach a picture and I will also share my code if needed...

[Dropdown menu getting covered by content (positioning) IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rySe7.jpg)

Comment: What's your code? Did you put a z-index?

Comment: _"and if needed I will also share my code if needed"_ See [mcve]

Comment: Put `z-index: 999;` on your dropdown.

Comment: @OgnjenStefanovic yep , that was it . didn't know about it until now...i will read more about what this is doing..thanks a lot for the fast repy

Comment: @Keoki just added z-index as Ognjen told me and it worked . thanks :D

Comment: Use `z-index` attribute for your dropdown and give it a number higher than the z-index of other containers, if you want it to remain on the top of other containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously stated you can use `z-index` to determine how elements are rendered on top of each other. Elements with an higher `z-index` are on top of elements with a lower `z-index`.

According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index):

> The z-index CSS property specifies the z-order of a positioned element and its descendants. When elements overlap, z-order determines which one covers the other. An element with a larger z-index generally covers an element with a lower one.

Answer (score 1):

Just but `z-index:999;` on your dropdown.

Objects with higher `z-index` number will go above those with lower numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Add the CSS attribute  `z-index: 999;` to your dropdown's CSS. Not necessarily should it be `999`, but just that `999` is the maximum one can use in `z-index`.

The property of `z-index` is that a division with a higher `z-index` will be displayed above a division with a lower number in the `z-index`, therefore allowing you to decide the hierarchy of the appearance of different divisions.

To know more, visit https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Answer (score 0):

If `z-index` is not solved, you can check nav container and if you found `overflow-y` you can comment that line.

Comment: @ Alfin If the image covering the nav bar is outside the nav component, hiding or quiting *overflow* would not solve the issue.

Comment: I said if you feel correctly set z-index, you can check the container of navbar, exist or not overflow-y(vertical), 

because if exist that's can cut your content appropriate navbar height. because some time ago, I experienced the same thing, and I think I correctly set the z-index that I have, after I checked again it turned out that my show dropdown was cut off by overflow-y. after I commented overflow-y and the problem was finished.